# Hibernate JDBC Connection Exception when maven building through shell script

Tags: java, hibernate, shell

I have a maven project which builds successfully if I do it through command line and fails if I do through script

My script was as follows:-

```
cd $PROJECT_HOME
mvn clean install -DskipTest
if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo 'run not successful exiting'; exit $rc
else
  echo 'build successful,deploying it to docker container'
fi
```

I get the error message as follows

> prepare(com.marketo.asset.smartlist.service.AutoSuggestServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 32.348 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

Comment: And you execute exactly the same line on exactly the same machine with exactly the same user?

Comment: @jokster, same cd to that directory and  mvn clean install -DskipTest